# Pandas changing a text to a unique value on large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Forgive me I'm quite new to pandas and python. I have managed to do this already but I'm sure there would be an easier and faster way. I have a large dataset and later on I perform `groupby` functions, sums, lambda functions etc, but if I leave what I'm grouping by as text it can take a very long time, but if I change it to unique numbers instead its much faster. I'm wondering if someone knows how to do this better.

Below is my code to get it done which is reasonably self explanatory, but seems like a very ugly approach to solve the problem. Does anyone know a better way.

```
df['key'] = df['name'].astype(str)
df1 = df[['key','name']].copy()
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset = ['key'])
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df1['key_id'] = df1.index
df1 = df1[['key','key_id']].copy()
df = df.merge(df1, how='left', on='key')
del df1
```

in the end an output should like

```
index   name   key_id 
0       adam   1
1       mick   2
2       john   3
3       adam   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that by converting the requested column to categorical, you will get the unique numerical labels you need

```
df['key'] = df['key'].astype('category')
# then you can access the unique indices by
unique_indices = df['key'].cat.codes
```